# About the measure of a sum

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory

I am new to measure-theory and I got a doubt after reading the next paragraph in my probability notes.

A coin is thrown repeatedly until a head appears. The sample space is $\Omega = \{o,+o,++o,+++o,... \}$ The probability of a configuration of heads and tails in $n$ throws is $1/2^n$

All the probabilities must add to 1.

$$\sum _{1}^{\infty} 1/2^n= \frac{{1/2}}{1-1/2} = 1$$

Here we have a countable set. I read in some comment that countable sets have measure zero.

a) Is that right?

Here the first terms won't have measure zero, i.e, $1/2^2$ has measure 1/4.

There's a point where the elements of the sum will become very small,for instance for n=100000.

b) If they are very small. Are they considered of measure 0?

c) If b) is right. How do you find the $n$ from which the elements of the sum have measure 0?

Comment: Countable subset of $\mathbb{R}^d$ has zero Lebesgue-measure, but it has infinite counting-measure. It depends on which measure you use, and here, it is definitely not a Lebesgue-measure.

Comment: Why isn't a Lebesgue-measure?

Comment: You already have the argument for that conclusion, and only need to interpret that differently. Since the Lebesgue-measure of any countable set is zero and your measure does not show that same property, they cannot coincide, letting alone the fact that $\Omega$ is not a subset of a Euclidean space. (Using a fancy terminology, the Lebesgue measure is atomless but your measure is purely atomic. So they cannot coincide.)

Comment: “I read in some comment that countable sets have measure zero”. Hello again, that was my comment, but if you look back to that question—I specified the *Lebesgue measure*. Be sure that there are different measures with different properties (like which sets have measure zero).

Comment: You are dealing here with a probability measure $P$ prescribed by $A\mapsto\sum_{n\in A}2^{-n}$ where $A$ denotes a subset of $\{1,2,3,\dots\}$. Note that e.g. $P(\{n\})=2^{-n}$ for $n\in\{1,2,3,\dots\}$ and $P(\{1,2,3\dots\})=1$.